# make fade in fade out smoother on ng show and hide

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass, ng-animate

here's the project I'm developing.

[Test Project Link](http://test.irisalbums.com/#/photographer)

Go to Products.

Click/Toggle <kbd>Flush Mounts</kbd> and <kbd>Press Books</kbd>

Observe the image below fades-in and out. As you can see, the first image fades out nicely but the second one pops-up instantly. How to make them both fade smooth and nicely?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="text-center font-zero">
    <a class="category" ng-class="{active: flushMount}" ng-click="flushMount = true" ng-init="flushMount = true">
        Flush Mounts
    </a>
    <a class="category" ng-class="{active: !flushMount}" ng-click="flushMount = false">
        Press Books
    </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="book-markers text-center">
        <div class="book-item" ng-show="flushMount">
           ...
        </div>
        <div class="book-item" ng-hide="flushMount">
           ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.book-item{
    @include transition(all 0.5s ease);
    opacity: 1;

    &.ng-hide-add, 
    &.ng-hide-remove{ 
        display: inline-block !important;
    }

    &.ng-hide{
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the Angular most important feature, use ng-view and split the two views into two partials....when "Flush Mounts" is clicked the flush mounts div fade in smoothly and when you click "Press Books" the press books div fade in smoothly too.
ng-view example : http://jsfiddle.net/carpasse/mcVfK/3/

```
   <ng-view>
   </ng-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you always see "Flush Mounts" (on the top), either fading in or fading out. Fading out takes twice as long. I think that has to do with Angular's animation process and the fact that animations run in one cycle.

You have defined `transition` on your base class and `display: inline-block;` for `ng-hide-add / remove`. The animation process first adds the add and remove classes. In your case this already adds a transition `display: none -> inline-block`. Then `ng-hide` is added, which adds another transition `opacity: 1 -> 0`. Fading in on the other hand only has one transition.

I'm not entirely sure whose fault it is. I'd suggest that at first you position the divs above each other in terms of z-index instead of y coordinate. You should do that anyway. Then you can put the transition on the hide class (or `.book-item.ng-hide`), not directly on `book-item`.